# List database data via jquery with FullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm returning some fields from the database, namely:
id, title, color, start, end, start_time, end_time and obs

In this case, when registering the fields using while in a php file and returning in a json array, the following example follows:

```
$query_events = "SELECT id, title, color, start, end, start_time, end_time, obs FROM events";
$resultado_events = $pdo->prepare($query_events);
$resultado_events->execute();

$events = [];

while($row_events = $result_events->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $id = $row_events['id'];
     $title = $row_events['title'];
     $color = $row_events['color'];
     $start = $row_events['start'];
     $end = $row_events['end'];
     $start_time = $row_events['start_time'];
     $end_time = $row_events['end_time'];
     $obs = $row_events['obs'];
    
     $events[] = [
         'id' => $id,
         'title' => $title,
         'color' => $color,
         'start' => $start,
         'end' => $end,
         'start_time' => $start_time,
         'time_end' => $time_end,
         'obs' => $obs
         ];
}

echo json_encode($events);
```

But it is not returning in the html of the page even listing. Returns only id, start and end

list records in database and display via json array with jquery in fullcalender

Comment: did you decode your JSON data on the HTML page?

Comment: Hello!

Yes, I used

echo json_encode($events);

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing - `start_time`, `time_end`, `obs` - those are all not default properties. So did you anything to configure Fullcalendar to use these for something?

Answer (score 1):

`'time_end' => $time_end` should be `'time_end' => $end_time`

use `$row_events = $resultado_events->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of `$row_events = $result_events->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

CORRECTED CODE:

```
$query_events = "SELECT id, title, color, start, end, start_time, end_time, obs FROM events";
$resultado_events = $pdo->prepare($query_events);
$resultado_events->execute();

$events = [];

while ($row_events = $resultado_events->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row_events['id'];
    $title = $row_events['title'];
    $color = $row_events['color'];
    $start = $row_events['start'];
    $end = $row_events['end'];
    $start_time = $row_events['start_time'];
    $end_time = $row_events['end_time'];
    $obs = $row_events['obs'];

    $events[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => $title,
        'color' => $color,
        'start' => $start,
        'end' => $end,
        'start_time' => $start_time,
        'end_time' => $end_time,
        'obs' => $obs
    ];
}

echo json_encode($events);
```